# Настройка rotation дисплей в kali linux

Tags: linux, rotation

У меня кали установлена на virtual box. Я новичок в линуксе и начал все смотреть, как все устроено и случайно в настройках дисплея нажал inverted в rotation и сохранил. В итоге экран в у меня перевернулся на 180, а обратно вернуть не могу потому что мышка не щелкает по экрану ,как будто он стал не видим для мышки.И это в пользователе root. У меня есть еще обычный пользователь, мб я я с помощью него смогу как то исправить ситуацию ,ибо как вы понимаете входя пользователем root экран у меня не кликабельный. Помогите пжлст.

Comment: *в пользователе root* о, сколько раз твердили миру!… да, работать надо под рядовым пользователем. не логиньтесь больше никогда как пользователь root и забудьте навсегда о том, что у этого пользователя на экране происходит. // а если такой же трюк проделаете с xrandr-ом уже от имени рядового пользователя, просто перезапустите x-сессию (ну или компьютер перезагрузите на самый тяжёлый случай).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну на винде же надо сидеть обязательно под `Администратор`. Пользователь же хозяин своего компьютера, а не какой-то кхм... Ну а чем линукс-то хуже?

Comment: По теме. Попробуй `mv ~/.config ~/.config_original && reboot`. Из пушки по воробьям и не факт, что поможет, но у нас же операционка для чёрных шапок.

Comment: в чем проблема то -- вы же на VB просто стартуйте новый ISO